Metadata on MultiDayEvent with NeatCleanCalendar Flutter
I am currently developing a flutter application based on a calendar and events.
The principle would be that when you click on a date on the calendar, all the events during that date appear. These events contain several pieces of information coming from an API. I use the metadata attribute of NeatCleanCalendar to insert the information coming from the API into a Map but this information is only inserted into the map for events on a single day , when I have events over several days, the map comes out empty. How can I fix this please ?
there is a example of my code :
     Future<void> getHistoric() async {
     var neatCleanCalendarEventList = <NeatCleanCalendarEvent>.obs;
     var historiqueModelList = <HistoriqueModel>;
     try {
     http.Response response = await HistoriqueRepository().getHistoric();
     var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
     if (response.statusCode == 201) {
       neatCleanCalendarEventList.clear();
       historiqueModelList.clear();
     for (int index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
      AudienceModel audience = AudienceModel.fromJson(result[index]["audience"]);
      StatutModel statut = StatutModel.fromJson(result[index]["statut"]);

      HistoriqueModel historiqueModel = HistoriqueModel(
        id: result[index]["id"],
        commentaire: result[index]["commentaire"],
        dateDebut: DateTime.parse(result[index]["dateDebut"]),
        dateFin: DateTime.parse(result[index]["dateFin"]),
        heureDebut: result[index]["heureDebut"],
        heureFin: result[index]["heureFin"],
        deleteAt: result[index]["deleteAt"],
        createdBy: result[index]["createdBy"],
        createdDate: DateTime.parse(result[index]["createdDate"]),
        lastModifiedBy: result[index]["lastModifiedBy"],
        lastModifiedDate: DateTime.parse(result[index]["lastModifiedDate"]),
        fullDateDebut: result[index]["fullDateDebut"],
        fullDateFin: result[index]["fullDateFin"],
        lieu: result[index]["lieu"],
        audience: audience,
        statut: statut,
      );
      historiqueModelList.add(historiqueModel);
      bool isMultiDay =
          historiqueModel.dateDebut!.day != historiqueModel.dateFin!.day;
      neatCleanCalendarEventList.add(
        NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
          historiqueModel.audience!.titre,
          description: historiqueModel.audience!.motif,
          startTime: DateTime(
              historiqueModel.dateDebut!.year,
              historiqueModel.dateDebut!.month,
              historiqueModel.dateDebut!.day,
              takeHourinTime(historiqueModel.heureDebut!),
              takeMinuteinTime(historiqueModel.heureDebut!)),
          endTime: DateTime(
              historiqueModel.dateFin!.year,
              historiqueModel.dateFin!.month,
              historiqueModel.dateFin!.day,
              takeHourinTime(historiqueModel.heureFin!),
              takeMinuteinTime(historiqueModel.heureFin!)),
          metadata: {
            'id': historiqueModel.id,
            'typeAudience': historiqueModel.audience!.typeAudience!.libelle,
            'createdDate': historiqueModel.createdDate,
            'motif': historiqueModel.audience!.motif,
            'nombrePersonne': historiqueModel.audience!.nombrePersonne,
            'DateDebut': historiqueModel.dateDebut,
            'DateFin': historiqueModel.dateFin,
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }
} catch (e) {}

}
